# unsorted double linked list corrupted Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, malloc, file-writing

```
#include<stdio.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
     #include<string.h>
     #include <time.h>
     typedef char string [50];


     typedef struct adresse{ 

        int  zip_code;
        string city;
      } 
     adresse Fr[27381996];// I will upload data to this table from the file

     int main (){

       int i=-1, line_nb=1; 
       int j=1;
       double timing=0.0;//This is for calculating the timing 
       //These upcoming lines are for opening the file 
       FILE * France_adr;  
       France_adr=fopen("france.csv","r");

       char adr[300]; 

       for(line_nb=1;line_nb<10;line_nb++)
        {
          time_t begin= time(NULL);//Here I start the timing 

          while((!feof(France_adr))&& (i<line_nb))
            {
    
                fgets(adr,300,France_adr);
                char* s = strdup(adr);
                char* val = strsep(&s,","); /* This is because in the file 
                there are some data that I 
                don't want to use and they are separated with a comma*/
                while(val!=NULL)
                {
        
                    val=strsep(&s,",");
                   // This is also to sort the data I want to get into my 
                   table
                   if(j==2 && i!=-1)
                     {
                       Fr[i].zip_code=atoi(val);
                       printf("%d | ",Fr[i].zip_code);
                      }
                   
                   j++;
                }

             i++;
             j=1;
             printf("\n");
           }
    fclose(France_adr);
    printf("\n\n");
 

    time_t end = time(NULL);
    duree += (double)(1000*(end-begin));

    //This section is for writing the timing and number of lines into a new 
    file
    FILE * donnee_t;
    donnee_t=fopen("Affichage_Donnee_Courbe.csv","a");
    fprintf(donnee_t,"\n %d,%f",i,duree);
    fclose(donnee_t);
    i=0;
   }
    return 0;
  }
```

I am working on this project where I have to upload huge data from a file. So what I got do is to display those lines of data on the terminal and see how much it takes for it to be displayed, and eventually creating a curve that shows how the time evolves according to the number of lines displayed (So
I write the number of lines displayed and time it took it to be displayed in another file .CSV). And since the file has 27 million line of data I thought of doing a loop for how many lines I want to display every time, But the terminal shows me that this error. I hope I explained the problem very well and I hope I can have your help. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQGb5.jpg)

Comment: Please post [mcve].

Comment: Strings allovated by `strdup` need to be freed. So you have a memory leak at least this one. Also see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I have tried to eliminate some parts of the code that might not be useful but I kept most of it, because I am not sure where is the problem coming from. Also, do you mean that I have to create a "char adr " with a bigger seize? Thank you for your help.